# Can't select a page using is_page()

Tags: pages

I've got 2 pages: "home" and "blog". In Settings they're set as following: Front page = "Home", "Posts page = "Blog".

However I can't select the "Blog" page: `is_page('blog')` doesn't validate, nor `is_home()` nor is_`front_page()`.

What condition could validate this page?

Comment: Try using this function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in my question, I did try is_home().

Comment: Where/when are you calling these [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)?  Please post some code that shows where you are calling them.

Comment: **1)** You have to call the conditional tags, at least, after `parse_query` action is fired. **2)** The right conditional tag, the only one that will work in this case, is `is_home()`, if this doesn't work or you are calling it to early or something in your install interfere with the global `$wp_query`.